# Error in reading text file as characters in C

Tags: c, linux

There's an error in reading this file.txt, how can i solve it? it should print the output of the text file but it prints first column as zeros and second column as first column!
here's the code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        
        pid_t p;
        int n1,m,n2,i=0,j,line=0,marks[30][2],z1,z2,pass,total;
        char c,w[3];
        FILE* fp;
        if(argc!=4){
                printf("Enter text file, number of TAs, minimum pass marks\n");
                return(0);
        }
        if((fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL){
                printf("File not available\n");
                return(0);
        }
        n1=atoi(argv[2]);
        m=atoi(argv[3]);

        while((c=fgetc(fp))!=-1){
                if(c=='\n'){
                        if(line==0){
                                w[i]='\n';
                                i=0;
                                n2=atoi(w);
                        }
                        else{
                                w[i]='\n';
                                i=0;
                                marks[line-1][1]=atoi(w);
                        }
                        line++;
                }
                else if(c=='\t'){
                        w[i]='\n';
                        i=0;
                        marks[line-1][0]=atoi(w);
                }
                else{
                        w[i++]=c;
                }
        }

        printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
        for(i=0;i<n2;i++){
                printf("%d\t%d\n",marks[i][0],marks[i][1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
```

[image]

Comment: Strings in C should always be NUL terminated. So everywhere you have `w[i] = '\n';` you should have `w[i] = '\0';` instead.

Comment: Stack smashing means the code is writing to an array with a bad index. With a debugger, you can find the line where the error occurs, and look at the array indexes that the code is using. Without a debugger, you should put an `if` statement (or an `assert`) before every array access. For example `marks[line-1][1] = atoi(w);` should be preceded by `if (line-1 < 0 || line-1 >= 30) { printf("Bad index: %d\n", line-1); exit(1); }`